# How to make "display: none" elements appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

In my form there are some fields which are not displayed when the page loads and I want them to be showed in and only if the user enters some values in some specific fields. Here is a fragment of html+css:

```
<style>
.more {
  display: none !important;
}
</style>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery('#budget_investito_imp').on('input',function(){
  jQuery(".more").show();
  if (jQuery("#iva").is(':filled') && jQuery("#budget_investito_imp").is(':filled')) {
    var iva_imposta = (parseFloat(jQuery("#budget_investito_imp").val()) * parseFloat(jQuery("#iva").val()))/100;
    var budget_investito_tot = parseFloat(jQuery("#budget_investito_imp").val()) + iva_imposta;
    if (budget_investito_tot != NaN)
        jQuery("#budget_investito_tot").val(budget_investito_tot);
  } else
    jQuery("#budget_investito_tot").val(0);

});


<p>
 <label>Budget investito (totale) </label>
 <span class="field">
 <input type="text" name="budget_investito_tot" id="budget_investito_tot" class="smallinput"   value="<?php echo $lavorazione['budget_investito_tot']  ?>" />
 </span>
</p>

<!-- HIDDEN!!! Appare solo se la lavorazione comprende una spesa -->
<p class="field more">  
 <label>Fornitore</label>
 <span>
  <input type="text" name="fornitore" id="fornitore" class="smallinput" value=""  />
 </span>
</p>

<p class="field more">  
 <label>Servizio</label>
 <span>
 <input type="text" name="servizio" id="servizio" class="smallinput" value=""  />
 </span>
</p>

<p class="field more">  
 <label>Dettagli spesa</label>
 <span>
 <textarea name="note" cols="40" rows="5" > </textarea>
</p>
<!-- HIDDEN -->

<p>
 <label>Data</label>
 <span class="field">
 <input id="datepicker" name="data_lavorazione" type="text" class="smallinput" value="<?php if (isset($_GET['id'])) echo $sistema->helper->invertData($lavorazione['data']);  ?>" /> 
 </span>
</p>
```

so there are 3

```
<p>
```

elements which should appear and I've tried to use jQuery function .show() but it has not worked. Any help?

Comment: Take `!important` out of your CSS rule. It should be a last resort anyway.

Comment: The only way around an `!important` rule is another `!important` rule of higher specificity or later cascading order.  If possible, remove the important rule.  If that's not possible, use `!important` when you set the display with javascript or another style rule.  Is it possible to remove `!important`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit as follows:

```
<style>
.more {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

Remove the `!important` and it should work as expected.

`jQuery(".more").show();` will define an inline style that will mark it as `display: block;`. But in your style tag, the `!important` takes precedence over the inline style, thats why you are not seeing the element appear.

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, remove `!important` from your display CSS. However, if you intend to keep it, another approach would be to remove the class from your DOM objects. However, if you intend to add `.more` again, you should select by something else.

```
jQuery(".more").removeClass("more");
```